# How to swipe custom content in bottom of activity in Android?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I wanna show some items in bottom of Activity, A total twelve options but I need to show only 4 at the same time and the others by swipe or scroll. I tried with a viewpager but I can't set it on bottom.

I wanna something like this.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance...

Comment: You can't position the `ViewPager` at the bottom? Why?

Comment: I don't know how to..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry if I'm late, but couldn't you just use `android:layout_gravity="bottom"` or `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`?